# Unable to invoke PSEXEC on remote machine using ActiveBatch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to execute a `bat` file on a remote computer using `psexec` through `ActiveBatch` and getting the rejection:

> "Could not start PSEXESVC service on 'remote machine', Activity
>   'ShellCommand' failed, ApplicationException in step 'ShellCommand':
>   Process exited with '2250'".

To run access the remote .bat I am using a `ShellCommand` step with the following command:

> psexec -u admincred -p pass -i 2 -d \remotecomputer cmd /c c:\msg.bat

I believe the path is correct since the bat file is on the c: drive and will execute if the `psexec` command is run through `cmd` on my machine. All the `.bat` does is call a message to another remote computer.

I believe the problem is getting `psexec` to run through the `ActiveBatch` `ShellCommand` on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know anything about ActiveBatch. But, if you can specify a command line, could you use something like this and not need psexec.exe?

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "Invoke-Command -ComputerName HOST001-ScriptBlock { & cmd.exe /C C:\Temp\msg.bat }"
```

A shortened form would be:

```
powershell -NoProfile "Invoke-Command HOST001 { & cmd.exe /C C:\Temp\msg.bat }"
```

If you must run the script as a different user, Invoke-Command has a -Credential parameter that can be used.